# using renderevent to add future events fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I'm trying to add an event for next month using:

```
var myEvent = {
  title:"my new event",
  start: $.fullCalendar.moment('2020-05-28T13:00'),
  end: $.fullCalendar.moment('2020-05-28T13:55')
};
$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'renderEvent', myEvent );
```

It doesn't seem to stick.

I've tried using the demo from documentation https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/renderEvent-demo but it doesn't seem to work there either.

Is there a way to do this or is this a limitation?

Comment: Any error, any issue please put more details ?

Comment: There really isn't more details. I get no errors or anything. Tried running the JS in console with the demo open to see if it added anything but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [renderEvent documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/renderEvent), you can optionally supply a third parameter named `stick`. The docs says this:

> Normally, the event will disappear once the calendar refetches its
>   event sources (example: when prev/next is clicked). However,
>   specifying `stick` as `true` will cause the event to be permanently fixed
>   to the calendar.

so

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'renderEvent', myEvent, true );
```

should solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my issue. I thought the stick parameter was for something else. Should of tried it!

Answer (score 1):

By navigation the fullCalendar refetch its events, you need to set the third params to `true` that will keep your added event by navigation.

Here is a simple demo https://codepen.io/nasser-ali-karimi/pen/VwYNdbj?editors=0010

```
$(function() {

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    defaultView: 'month',
    header: {
      center: 'addEventButton'
    },
    customButtons: {
      addEventButton: {
        text: 'add event...',
        click: function() {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
              title:"my new event",
              start: "2020-02-09T07:00",
              end: "2020-02-09T07:50"
            } , true  );

        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: During the checking be sure that you check the currect date

Comment: Hey! Thank you for the answer but if you change the start and end date to 2020-02-08 while still on January you will see it wont add to February calendar. But if you're on the February calendar it will add. This is where my problem is.

Comment: okay, this is new point that you should mention to your main question.

Comment: I thought it was implied because of the dates I was giving with the demo code. But the sticky parameter seems to do the trick. Thank for your answers.